# bibtex-field-strings-alist usage

Tags: bibtex

I'd like bibtex-clean-entry to change a few strings within titles for me - for example I'd like it to replace "CO2" with "CO$_2$".  Setting up variable bibtex-field-strings-alist like this

```
(setq bibtex-entry-format '(opts-or-alts required-fields numerical-fields strings))
(setq bibtex-field-strings-alist
      '((("title") "CO2" "CO$_2$")))
```

replaces "CO2" with "} # CO$_2$ # {".  Close but no cigar.  I suspect the unwanted braces and hashes have to do with the definition of "BibTeX string constant" in the docs for bibtex-field-strings-alist, but I'm not spotting anything about what that means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Disclaimer: I don't know much about BibTeX or `bibtex.el`, so take what follows with the appropriate grain of salt]

I think you misunderstand what this is supposed to do. BibTeX string constants are basically abbreviations:

```bibtex
@string{ foo = "a very long string that I would not like to have to type constantly" }
```

You can then use it in a field like this:

```bibtex
@Book{ key
   author = {A.U.Thor}
   title  = {This is } # foo # { indeed}
   ...
}
```

The hash is a string concatenation operator and the string constant `foo` gets replaced by its definition when you `bibtex` your file.

What the `bibtex-field-strings-alist` mechanism allows you to do is to not worry about what's inside and what's outside the braces or getting the string concatenation operators right. You can say

```el
(setq bibtex-field-strings-alist
      '((("title") "foo" "foo")))
```

and write the entry as

```bibtex
@Book{ key
   author = {A.U.Thor}
   title  = {This foo indeed}
   ...
}
```

Then `C-c C-c` gets you the previous form of the entry which is then properly expanded using the definition of the string. That's all it does.

`bibtex.el` provides some facilities but to understand where/when/how to use them, you need a grounding in BibTeX itself. This question is just barely about Emacs: it's more about BibTeX, so it would probably be more appropriate for the [TeX-LaTeX SE site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).

PS. BTW, when you change `bibtex-field-strings-alist` (or as in your previous question, `bibtex-field-braces-alist`), you don't need to restart emacs, but you do need to reinitialize the variable `bibtex-field-strings-opt` (or `bibtex-field-braces-opt`) to `nil`.

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful.  I did indeed misunderstand what a BiBTex string constant is/does/is for.  The phrase "BiBTex string constant" shows up in the documentation for bibtex-field-strings-alist and, as far as I can tell, no where else.  Your post filled in my knowledge gap - thanks!

Comment: I still believe this is an emacs, not a BibTeX question.  What I want is for bibtex-clean-entry (an emacs/bibtex.el function) to replace "CO2" with "CO$_2$" in addition to everything else it already does.  I had hoped setting up bibtex-field-strings-alist could accomplish this; I see now that's not really what it's for.   I guess I'll have to dust off my elisp coding skills.  elisp is definitely not my strong suit so I'd hoped there was a pre-canned way to accomplish this.  Cheers :)